# What is the consumption of a still car?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I.e. when you wait at a traffic light, without stopping your combustion engine.

( My long term curiosity is about some empirical raw approximation of the consumption in liters/minute. Easy to measure at road speed, but not at rest - or very slow speed. Ultimately I'ld like to get orders of magnitudes, for main factors isolated, but here for a start a global number at rest is all I seek for. ).

To settle numbers if needed, I can give the setup for my (French) car: gasoil, electronic injection, 130 ch din, 2.0 liters. But I'm curious for other setups as well.

Comment: Cars come in a great variety of shapes, sizes and technology. This will depend on total displacement, fuel type, idle speed, the presence or absence of variable displacement technology, and many more factors. Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I totally rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against using MPG.

-Consider the engine at idle and the fact that it must stay at operating temperature. Consider convection and radiation emitted from the engine, and then the 20% efficiency. Using that, you should be able to deduce a possible fuel consumption.

If you want to try the real deal, remember that engines pull intake plenum vacuum at idle which makes the air less dense and makes the engine appear smaller in order to consume a balanced air-fuel ratio based on mass. That, you can definitely solve, depending on the displacement. Air is .00238 slugs per cubic inch. 14.7:1 by mass for fuel consumption. Some engines pull up to 22 in-hg of vacuum at idle. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned mpg is pretty much meaningless when stationary as it is zero regardless of how much fuel is actually used.

However the key thing is that there is a certain base load on a running engine which generally doesn't change that much with speed. This is comprised of a few different things:

- Induction load : each cylinder much suck air into the combustion chamber through valves, ducts and filters this costs a certain amount of energy. This tends to be a bit larger at part throttle (for gasoline engines, not diesel)  as the throttle valve restricts airflow.
- Internal friction : IC engines have a lot of moving parts and bearing surfaces on crank bearings, con-rods, valves, piston rings etc etc all contribute to load on the engine.
- Exhaust : this is assisted by residual pressure in the combustion chamber but even so back pressure form the exhaust system including mufflers, catalytic converters etc will generate some resistance on the exhaust stroke. Turbos can potentially reclaim some energy form the exhaust but don't really do much at idle.
- Combustion : the combustion chamber has a fixed volume so there is a minimum amount of fuel required for proper ignition. So at low revs combustion efficiency may be reduced. This is helped a lot by active engine management which can adjust air/fuel ration and ignition timing in respect to rpm.
- Auxiliary Systems : fuel pumps, oil pumps water pumps, air conditioning and alternator all put a load on the engine. Indeed there may be more load on the cooling system when stationary as the only airflow through the radiator is from the fan.

It is also worth noting that these loads, although relatively small in terms of overall engine power are more or less constant regardless of the external load on the engine and so take a much bigger bite out of the thermal efficiency at low speeds as they are the main load. This does not necessarily mean that the engine itself  is working 'less efficiently' as such at lower speeds.

Some care is needed here with analysis as an idling engine, by conventional measures has infinitely bad fuel economy and thermal  efficiency as both are measures of useful work vs energy consumed and when stationary you are doing no 'useful work' but still consuming energy. So it is much more useful to look at fuel consumer per second in  these conditions.

Comment: "it is much more useful to look at fuel consumer per second in these conditions":   ...which is exactly what I'm seeking for ;-) . would you have an order of magnitude - say, assuming electronic injection ?

(Thanks for all this interesting decomposition of effects, anyway ).

Comment: It will vary a lot according to engine design ie large capacity engine will use more but it is probably safe to say that idle loads will be  a few horsepower maybe 1-5% of total engine power perhaps in the order of a few KW